# How to change a string to a multiCharacter literal in C++?

Tags: c++

Say I have things below:

```
int i = 'abc';
```

If there way to change a string to a multiCharacter literal, like below

```
char* str="abc";
int j = ?
```

(we want to set `int j= 'abc'` too).

But how to do that with a string?

Comment: And what do you want to do to that `int` variable further down?

Comment: "multicharacter literals" aren't defined by the C++ spec, though they're supported by most compilers.  The main difference is that `"abc"` is the same as `'abc\0'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the string data to an integer during runtime.

Knowing that the `char` type can be treated as an integer, it can therefore be placed into an integer.

If we assume a platform with 8 bits per character, the default `char` type is unsigned and an `unsigned int` is 32-bits, we can create an integer from the characters:

```
char text[] = "abcd";
unsigned int value;
value = text[0] << 24
      + text[1] << 16
      + text[2] << 8
      + text[3];
```

There may be more problems involved if you want to convert a string literal into a multibyte literal *at compile time*.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's the answer I want.

Comment: I think your example has an issue with operator precedence. `<<` has lower precedence than `+`. This means that it would evaluate `24 + text[1]`. I doubt that is the intent.

Answer (score 1):

C99 6.4.4.4/10:

> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., 'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is implementation-defined."

C++11 2.14.3/1:

> A multicharacter literal has type int and implementation-defined
>   value.

Therefore, without knowing what your specific implementation does, you cannot reproduce the same result. Once you do know what it does, you should be able to compute `j` yourself without any problems.

Comment: How can i find my specific implementation please? Thankx

Comment: @JieChen It is a bit hard for anyone but yourself to divine which C++ implementation you are using.